# Not Able to scrape website using Rvest and Rselenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

Here Is my code but it Returns Null Values
It is Working fine with Individual links but returning Null values when i am using with for loop Can anyone point out error in this code.

````
structure(list(Property_sku = c("1B - Anantara - 316", "1B - Mag540 - 306", 
  "1B- Downtown Views - 3109", "1B- Tiara Tanzanite- 504", "1B-Address JBR - 1107"
  ), Airbnb_link = c("https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/552037226634913505?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1654086364_RJjGWicrEoR%2FB%2Bgu", 
  "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/54045333?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1644216409_ftDpMWrY34gbixtv", 
  "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/54360731?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1649243904_EjWEoEoKTYpW1zaT", 
  "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/565630731118783569?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1649245563_mMhnLLQhlqTS26sb", 
  "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/53245239?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1644215345_i3xkL5TcGvenCy2j"
  )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
  ))
  structure(list(Property_sku = c("1B - Anantara - 316", "1B - Mag540 - 306", 
  "1B- Downtown Views - 3109", "1B- Tiara Tanzanite- 504", "1B-Address JBR - 1107"
  ), Airbnb_link = c("https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/552037226634913505?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1654086364_RJjGWicrEoR%2FB%2Bgu", 
  "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/54045333?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1644216409_ftDpMWrY34gbixtv", 
  "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/54360731?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1649243904_EjWEoEoKTYpW1zaT", 
  "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/565630731118783569?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1649245563_mMhnLLQhlqTS26sb", 
  "https://www.airbnb.co.in/rooms/53245239?preview_for_ml=true&source_impression_id=p3_1644215345_i3xkL5TcGvenCy2j"
  )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
  ))
  
  ### Code I Written
  
  
  library(rvest)
  library(tidyverse)
  library(RSelenium)
  rD <-  rsDriver(browser="chrome",port=4234L,chromever="104.0.5112.79")
  remDr <- rD$client
  for(i in 1:length(Aug_Active_property_airbnb_review$Airbnb_link)){
    remDr$navigate(paste0(Aug_Active_property_airbnb_review$Airbnb_link[[i]]))
    Sys.sleep(1)
    Aug_Active_property_airbnb_review$listing_name <- sapply(Aug_Active_property_airbnb_review$Airbnb_link[[i]],function(url){
      read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>% html_nodes("h1._fecoyn4") %>% html_text2()
      Sys.sleep(1)
    }, USE.NAMES = FALSE)}```
````

Comment: sorry, i haven't pasted full code. can you point out the error in code as its returning null value

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are trying to scrape the title. Note that I am using FireFox rather than Chrome

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = free_port())
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

get_title <- function(url) {
  remDr$navigate(url)
  remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_element("h1._fecoyn4") %>% 
    html_text2()
}

airbnb %>%  
  mutate(title = map_chr(Airbnb_link, get_title)) %>% 
  relocate(title)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  title                                              Property_sku           Airbnb_link
  <chr>                                              <chr>                  <chr>      
1 # Summer Deal# Lux Hideout at Palm by bnbmehomes   1B - Anantara - 316    https://ww…
2 Deluxe 1BR | 5 mins to Expo | by bnbmehomes        1B - Mag540 - 306      https://ww…
3 Skyscrapper | Connected to DM | by bnbmehomes      1B- Downtown Views - … https://ww…
4 LUX 1 BR Sun Sand & Shadow| Pvt Beach | bnbmehomes 1B- Tiara Tanzanite- … https://ww…
5 Private Beach in a bnbme Designer Apartment        1B-Address JBR - 1107  https://ww…
```